# Why don't the "trapped warm air" just fly out of the holes in blankets?

Tags: thermodynamics, convection

I've read a lot of explanations that the holes of a blanket somehow trap air which keeps the air in place.(including this: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/10lj0h/eli5_why_do_quilts_and_blankets_with_holes_in/) My question is if cold air can enter the blanket through these holes, then why can't air heated by your body fly out these holes as well? I do understand that these holes will slow down air circulation. But how do these holes "hold" air? And if they don't hold air, just merely slow down the circulation, then wouldn't a blanket with less holes be more efficient i.e. warmer? If so, then what is the importance of these holes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warmed air does flow out the holes in a blanket- just very slowly, because the holes are small and the air is viscous.

Answer (score 1):

Who says it air doesn't flow out? That's a good thing as long it is lower than without the blanket.

Remember that your body is continuously generating heat so to maintain a comfortable temperature you also want a continuous flow of heat out. The higher the temperature difference between under the blanket and the outside air, the faster heat will be lost. Eventually a temperature equilibrium is reached under the blanket when it rises high enough that the rate of heat added by your body equals the rate of heat lost to the outside.

Also there are comfort concerns such as moisture build-up and breathability.

It would be different if you were trying to retain heat on a passive object like a hot rock where you want to retain as much heat as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by "holes", both your question and the linked one are referring to tears or rips in the blanket, not to the small-scale voids inside the fabric between the fibers of the material.

The question you've linked to on reddit is asking "why does the blanket still work, even if it has holes".  It does *still* work.  It doesn't work *better* than a blanket without holes.

Yes, a blanket without holes would be warmer.  The holes have no importance other than to raise the original question of why the blanket still functions.

But even though a hole is present, if it's fairly small (a few cm), it still reduces airflow and convection.  Heat loss through the hole will be greater than through the material, but will still be slower than if the surrounding blanket were missing.